# A or the noun of something

Tags: articles

> As the product of a lonely childhood, Wilson began studying insects at the age of 9.

Is it okay if I use "... a product of a lonely childhood" and still maintain the original meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

This is actually a good illustration of the difference in nuance between the *definite* and the *indefinite* article.  In this case, the definite article indicates we are only interested in *one* product of the lonely childhood -- namely, Wilson himself. If, instead, we used the indefinite article, it would indicate there are possibly *many* products, which would distract from the focus on Wilson.

For example, to [paraphrase the physicist Neil deGrasse Tyson](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/484586-the-atoms-of-our-bodies-are-traceable-to-stars-that):

> As **the** products of ancient cosmic explosions, the atoms in our bodies are connected to everything in the universe.  We are not figuratively, but literally, *stardust*.

Suppose instead we wanted to focus on just one of many products:

> As **a** product of ancient cosmic explosions, and because it is extremely stable, iron is one of the most common elements in the universe.